# How can I make an AWS Batch job connect to a VPC endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I'm trying to see if I can use AWS Batch to perform scheduling so I don't have to deploy my own system.  What I need the scheduler to do is perform a GRPC call at a given time.  The GRPC would be an exposed port in my Docker Swarm inside VPC, so it can route to the appropriate service, but I can't find in the **Job Definition** page any notion of associating a VPC.

Comment: Why use batch for that? A lambda + cloudwatch trigger based on a schedule sounds like a simpler approach. Or do you need long running processing after the call was made? Anyway: the vpc would be configured on the compute environment, not on the job definition: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/Batch_GetStarted.html